# Blender 2.8 Comb hair strands with children

Tags: particles, hair

I'm struggling to find a way to comb hair particles in Blender 2.8 with children particles included in the Edit Particles mode.

In other words, is it possible, and if yes how, to view and comb all strands, including children particles in the Edit Particles mode?

In other other words... Can I view to outcome of the comb immediately.

Actually, I can only comb the parents, go back and forth Object mode-Edit particles... which is tedious and ineffective… I cannot control the outcome.

Thanks for any input, advice and cheers

DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

In 2.8 you can find it in the "Active tool and workspace settings"-Tab when in particle edit mode.

Comment: It was helpful and did the work, thanks @Coffeehouse ! I hope I accept it properly, kindly advise if I didn't mark it correctly.